# Erro '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'tuple'

Tags: python

Comecei a aprender python recentemente e me deparei com um erro em um dos exercícios que não sei como resolver.

Aparece a seguinte mensagem em relação à 10ª linha:

> TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'tuple'

Eu utilizo o replit.

O enunciado do exercício é o seguinte:

Escreva um programa para aprovar o empréstimo bancário para a compra de uma casa. Pergunte o valor da casa, o salário do comprador e em quantos anos ele vai pagar. A prestação mensal não pode exceder 30% do salário ou então o empréstimo será negado.

Segue a minha resolução:

```
nome = str(input('Qual é o seu nome? '))
print(f'Olá, {nome}, tudo bem? Vou auxliar você na compra da sua casa.')
casa = float(input('Qual é o valor da casa a ser comprada? '))
salario = float(input(f'{nome}, qual é o valor do seu salário? '))
ano = int(input(f'Certo. {nome}, em quantos anos você gostaria de pagar? '))
meses = ano*12
prestações = casa/meses
print (f'O valor da prestação será de R${prestações} mensais.')
parcela = salario*0,3
if prestações <= parcela:
  print('Empréstimo pode ser aprovado!')
else:
  print('Empréstimo negado!')
```

Na resolução do professor ocorre tudo certo, mas na minha aparece esse erro, alguma ideia do que seja?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Se tratando apenas do erro que mencionou na pergunta, na linha que indicou:

```
if prestações <= parcela:
```

Você está comparando um [número de ponto flutuante](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) com uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences), que não podem ser comparados diretamente da forma que está. Uma tupla funciona como uma lista, mas tem suas próprias características (veja as referências), então não podemos comparar uma lista diretamente com um número. Isso acontece porque você usou, duas linhas acima, uma vírgula (",") no lugar de ponto (".") para representar uma casa decimal (em inglês, "." é usado como separador de casas decimais):

```
parcela = salario*0,3
```

Isso fez com que a variável `parcela` ficasse com o seguinte valor de tupla, porque a vírgula separou as expressões `salario*0` de `3`:

```
(0.0, 3)
```

Neste exemplo, eu digitei "3" na pergunta "NOME, qual é o valor do seu salário?". Perceba, também, que a saída separou o primeiro valor decimal com "." e não com ",".

Basta trocar a vírgula por ponto (`0,3` por `0.3`) e seu código deve funcionar da forma que esperava.

Comment: Muito obrigada!!